# I can't import termcolor libraries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good evening, I'm doing a Python script that automates a very heavy task and to decorate it a little use termcolor to color the texts. Then I use a tool that converts it to EXE using the Cx_Freeze-5.1.1 libraries.

On several occasions I got that the amount and works well, but I've been three days behind this and I can not make it work now. But if I charge a module that if you use that Liberia to return to the EXE load me with the colors and everything.

If someone can lend me a hand I thank you, greetings.

Link to code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cuYNSWGf83oCW0Zxci1wf54fnzfHhc7e/view?usp=sharing

Sorry, i dont know how to post in here! :,(

Comment: don't worry we'll get to it very soon

Comment: Are you sure the module termcolor is installed?

Comment: Goodnight! I'm sure 99% hehe when loading one of the modules in the folder. \ modules loads the termcolor library, and this is next to the libraries compiled by Cx_Freeze-5.1.1 when I build the .exe for what it gives me understand that they are there but do not load them initially. That is, I start the exe, it does not load the libraries (it puts values ​​like 3] m / where the color should be). Then I run a module with .py extension of the. \ Modules folder and load the liberia. Then I go back to the main menu (exe) and load the colors.

Comment: If you want I can upload screenshots and other things if necessary.

Thank you very much for the attention, greetings :)

Comment: you can use pyinstaller to do the convertion to ```.exe``` since for now it is the most maintained and updated converter for python projects, but alse read the doc of cx_freeze since in both the pyinstaller and this one's case you may have to add them to the configuration files, which is not as hard as it sounds. Good luck. Anyways I was referring to a pip install

Comment: Good afternoon! Thank you very much for the information. I read the documentation of cx_freeze and found a way to import external liberias, but it did not work :( strangely, it worked by placing this the following command --> os.system ('cls') <-- at the beginning of the loop. I do not know why it works like that, but it gives me to understand that once I load a system liberia I can load the others, if I am confused that someone corrects me please.

Greetings and many thanks to surge10 and the forum!